# Scheme - detecting aux keyword

Tags: scheme, keyword, syntactic-sugar

I have just finished up the compilers course at IU and am trying to add a few more forms to my little "scheme". We added several forms into our language via syntactic sugar where a full scheme would typically use macro-expansion (and and or were the main ones). The problem I've come across is desugaring a cond statement.

As a note: I am going back and forth between Chez and Petite Chez as I work.

I am trying to handle all of the cond clause forms. When handling the (test => expr) form, I seem to be running into problems working with the =>. I can't seem to do anything to it without getting a misplaced aux keyword error or having the clause fall through to the next line in my match statement.

Any ideas on how I can detect this keyword?

Comment: It might help if you could post some code or explain a bit more about what you have already done.

Comment: `syntax-rules` need to be ordered from the most specific to the least specific. I got the same error message, because of the wrong order in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my own Scheme metacircular interpreter some time ago, with support for the `=>` syntax in the `cond` special form. In essence, this is what I had to do:

```
(define (expand-actions clause)
  (let ((exp (sequence->exp (cond-actions clause))))
    (if (cond-has-then? clause)
        (make-application exp
                          (if (cond-else-clause? clause)
                              #t
                              (list (cond-predicate clause))))
        exp)))
```

When iterating over all the clauses (pairs of predicates and actions) of a `cond` expression, I expand each action and ask if the `=>` token is present in the clause (using `cond-has-then?`). If `=>` was found, I apply the action part of the clause to the predicate.

Here's the complete piece of code in charge of evaluating `cond` expressions in my interpreter, the main procedure (the one called from `eval`) is `cond->if`, which transforms a `cond` expression into a series of nested `if` expressions, and also deals with the `=>` syntax; I hope this is helpful for you:

```
(define (cond->if exp)
  (expand-clauses (cond-clauses exp)))

(define cond-clauses cdr)

(define (cond-has-then? clause)
  (eq? (cadr clause) '=>))

(define cond-predicate car)

(define (cond-actions clause)
  (if (cond-has-then? clause)
      (cddr clause)
      (cdr clause)))

(define (cond-else-clause? clause)
  (eq? (cond-predicate clause) 'else))

(define (expand-clauses clauses)
  (if (null? clauses)
      (void)
      (let ((first (car clauses))
            (rest  (cdr clauses)))
        (if (cond-else-clause? first)
            (if (null? rest)
                (expand-actions first)
                (error "ELSE clause isn't last -- COND->IF" clauses))
            (make-if (cond-predicate first)
                     (expand-actions first)
                     (expand-clauses rest))))))

(define (expand-actions clause)
  (let ((exp (sequence->exp (cond-actions clause))))
    (if (cond-has-then? clause)
        (make-application exp
                          (if (cond-else-clause? clause)
                              #t
                              (list (cond-predicate clause))))
        exp)))

(define (make-if predicate consequent alternative)
  (list 'if predicate consequent alternative))

(define (sequence->exp seq)
  (cond ((null? seq) '())
        ((last-exp? seq) (first-exp seq))
        (else (make-begin seq))))

(define (last-exp? seq)
  (null? (cdr seq)))

(define first-exp car)

(define (make-application proc . args)
  (cond ((null? args) (list proc))
        ((list? (car args)) (cons proc (car args)))
    (else (cons proc args))))

(define (make-begin seq)
  (cons 'begin seq))
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason my pattern matcher was giving me problems with how I used eq? The first time. Upon redoing it, eq? Worked like a charm.